# Choosing Right Type of Filter for time series data

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, kalman-filters, digital-filters

I am working on a `temperature` time-series data which is very noisy. I am trying to measure true `low` and `high` temperature but because of noise, I can not apply `peak detection` directly. I need to do some filtering. Since sampling frequency `Fs` is not known for this data, I have applied two types of filter

1. Kalman filter

[image]

2. Median filter
   [image]

`orange` lines are the original signal and `blue` lines are filtered signal. The median filter seems good in this example which is preserving edges.

I want to know what are other types of filters which I can apply to get rid of noise without affecting the sharp edges of the signal.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by true low and high temperature. For the given time-series plots, which value you will prefer to call a true low or high?

Comment: I mean to say, I want to preserve edges and want to remove noise from signal. Thereafter, peak detection would work properly.

Comment: How about if you first take numerical differentiation of your signal and then smooth the resultant signal?

Comment: Amplitude would be lost in this case.

Comment: You are looking for the location of a peak and amplitude of the signal at that location. You may obtain location from a differentiation scheme which can be used later to gather signal amplitude from the original signal.

Comment: I found this to be helpful, maybe would be for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data